# Appending a value in Sass

Tags: css, loops, sass, append

I am working with BEM and Sass, using the following `@mixin`:

```
@mixin modifier($modifiers...) {
  $result: '';

  @each $modifier in $modifiers {
    $result: append($result, '#{&}--#{$modifier}');
  }

  @at-root #{$result} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

This function usually handles a single `modifier` (i.e. `foo--bar`). But I have tried to construct it so if there is ever a scenario where two modifiers compounded elicits a unique behaviour. This is why the `@mixin` can handle multiple arguments if necessary.

The problem is the unexpected behaviour resulting when I pass two arguments. Consider the following:

```
.foo {
  display: block;

  @include modifier('bar', 'baz') {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The intended output is as follows:

```
.foo {
  display: block;
}
.foo--bar.foo--baz {
  display: none;
}
```

However, it seems a space is added when I append items and so `.foo--baz` is actually treated as a descendant of `.foo--bar`, as with the following example:

```
.foo {
  display: block;
}

.foo--bar .foo--baz {
  display: none;
}
```

How do I prevent `$result` from adding spaces between each `append()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the output you want by using string concatenation instead of the `append()` function:

```
@mixin modifier($modifiers...) {
   $result: '';

   @each $modifier in $modifiers {
      $result: '#{$result}#{&}--#{$modifier}';
   }

   @at-root #{$result} {
      @content;
   }
}
```

Comment: Much more concise than the hack I went with. I'm going with your solution. Thanks  ;)